# save bookmark with relative path to current-site

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

As part of work, the same webapp is hosting at multiple location for different units

e.g.

```
 http://site1.come/path-to-some-page
 http://site2.come/path-to-some-page
```

Now I have a bookmark for site1 saved as

```
 http://site1.come/path-to-some-page
```

but for site2 I will have to again create a new bookmark. I have to deal with a new domain name each week, it is pain to do this task again and again each week.

Can I not save bookmarks relative to current host

E.g.

```
 http://{CURRENT_HOST}/path-to-some-page
```

This will save me lot of pain of saving bookmark for each new website

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
javascript:void(window.location.href = '/path-to-some-page');
```

Is another way of bookmarking a relative path.

Comment: I like the void trick for Bookmarklets. I've always used an anonymous function, but this is cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't seen a way to save a relative or root-relative link without resorting to a bookmarklet.

As far as a bookmarklet is concerned, it's relatively easy to generate one that will take you to whatever path you'd like:

```
javascript:(rel=>{location=rel.startsWith('/')?`${location.protocol}//${location.host}${rel}`:`${location.protocol}//${location.host}${location.pathname}/${rel}`})('/path')
```

Replace `'path'` at the end with a properly escaped string containing whatever path you'd like. Note that this will differentiate between relative and root-relative paths based on whether they start with a `/` character.

In long form:

```
(rel => {
  location =
    // if the relative path starts with /
    rel.startsWith('/')
      // go to http(s)://{domain}/{relative path}
      ? `${location.protocol}//${location.host}${rel}`
      // otherwise go to http(s)://{domain}/{current path}/{relative path}
      : `${location.protocol}//${location.host}${location.pathname}/${rel}`
// call the function providing the relative path to use
})('/path')
```